# select rows with specific bits equal to zero in hive

Tags: hive, bit

I want to select all rows having bits 10-12 of an int column ("flags") equal to 0 in hive.

What sort of query would I write to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `shifleft()` and bit-wise and:

```
where (intcol & shiftleft(1, 10)) = 0 and
      (intcol & shiftleft(1, 11)) = 0 and
      (intcol & shiftleft(1, 12)) = 0
```

Comment: I get a message saying: Invalid function 'shiftleft'

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob . . . https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF.